# npm install error code 1 in vue.js when trying to create a project

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

I have a problem while creating my project with vue.js, wanting to start to take in hands this framework, I find myself facing a wall. The problem is that every time I enter the following command line in the windows command prompt I get this error:

```
(c) Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>vue --version
@vue/cli 4.5.15

C:\WINDOWS\system32>vue create other-one


Vue CLI v4.5.15
? Please pick a preset: Manually select features
? Check the features needed for your project: Babel, CSS Pre-processors, Linter
? Pick a CSS pre-processor (PostCSS, Autoprefixer and CSS Modules are supported by default): Sass/SCSS (with node-sass)
? Pick a linter / formatter config: Basic
? Pick additional lint features: Lint on save
? Where do you prefer placing config for Babel, ESLint, etc.? In dedicated config files
? Save this as a preset for future projects? No


Vue CLI v4.5.15
✨  Creating project in C:\WINDOWS\system32\other-one.
  Initializing git repository...
⚙️  Installing CLI plugins. This might take a while...


added 1277 packages, and audited 1278 packages in 2m

85 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

28 vulnerabilities (17 moderate, 11 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
  Invoking generators...
  Installing additional dependencies...

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\WINDOWS\system32\other-one\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\WINDOWS\system32\other-one\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Le fichier projet n'existe pas.
npm ERR! Commutateur�:�build/binding.sln
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\other-one\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "C:\Users\kevin\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded C:\Users\kevin\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe C:\Users\kevin\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version `C:\Users\kevin\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe -c "import sys; print "2.7.15
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 16.13.1
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '16.13.1' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "16.13.1"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 16.13.1
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 16.13.1
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: C:\WINDOWS\system32\other-one\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? C:\WINDOWS\system32\other-one\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: C:\WINDOWS\system32\other-one\node_modules\node-sass\build\config.gypi
npm ERR! (node:2840) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: C:\WINDOWS\system32\other-one\node_modules\node-sass\config.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: C:\WINDOWS\system32\other-one\node_modules\node-sass\common.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "msvs"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Users\kevin\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\other-one\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-G',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=2015',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\other-one\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\other-one\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\kevin\\.node-gyp\\16.13.1\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\kevin\\.node-gyp\\16.13.1',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\other-one\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\Users\\kevin\\.node-gyp\\16.13.1\\<(target_arch)\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\other-one\\node_modules\\node-sass',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\other-one\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp verb command build []
npm ERR! gyp verb build type Release
npm ERR! gyp verb architecture x64
npm ERR! gyp verb node dev dir C:\Users\kevin\.node-gyp\16.13.1
npm ERR! gyp verb found first Solution file build/binding.sln
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "msbuild.exe" in PATH - finding location in registry
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\WINDOWS\system32\other-one\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\other-one\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\WINDOWS\system32\other-one\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-04T22_59_04_505Z-debug.log
 ERROR  command failed: npm install --loglevel error --legacy-peer-deps
```

I tried the `npm cache clean --force` then manually delete node_modules and package-lock.json and `npm i`. Doesn't work.

I also tried to change my python version and change it in my enviromental variables. Not working too.

Last step was to delete node and install last version (17.3.0) either the (16.13.1) and an other version from 14 release. Nothing seems to work.

So if anybody got an answer ... Please...

Thanks for reading it, even if you don't have any answer.

Comment: What Node version are you running (try `node --version`)? You want to be using V 16.13.1 or later

Comment: I'm using the last TLS version wich is 16.13.1, dont know really wich version i want, just want it to work .

Comment: whoa! wait, I just noticed you're building out of the `C:\WINDOWS\system32` directory. Why are you doing that?! Can you try in a user directory, like a folder on your desktop?

Comment: Because it was set as default and didn't notice it, i change the directory and i don't have any error but still got vulnerabilities, is that important ? 
`
added 1277 packages, and audited 1278 packages in 20s

85 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

68 vulnerabilities (57 moderate, 11 high)`

Comment: Sorry, you didn't tag me so I didn't see your comment. That means it's working. You should go through the vulnerabilities and see which ones pose an actual threat, or check with the Vue devs. If this project is just a test that won't be exposed to the public, then you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: I'll add an answer with the solution discussed above.

Answer (score 3):

**The first thing you need to know is that different versions correspond to different uses**

- **node corresponding node-sass**
  [image]
- **node-sass corresponding sass-loader**

```
sass-loader 4.1.1，node-sass 4.3.0  

sass-loader 7.0.3，node-sass 4.7.2  

sass-loader 7.3.1，node-sass 4.7.2  

sass-loader 7.3.1，node-sass 4.14.1
```

---

### the sloution 1

if your `node 16+`
1-1、uninstall

`npm uninstall node-sass --save`
`npm uninstall sass-loader --save`

1-2、install
`npm i node-sass@6.0.1 -S`
`npm i sass-loader@10.0.1 -S`

else if your node less than  `16`,  You can install according to the above version

### the sloution 2(recommend)

- use `dart-sass`

1-1、uninstall

`npm uninstall node-sass --save`
`npm uninstall sass-loader --save`

1-2、install
`npm i sass@1.32 -S`
`npm i sass-loader@10.0.5 -S`

Comment: This makes sense since it's a gyp issue

Comment: Thanks for your answer !
So i'm running the 16.13.1 node version, so i tried the first solution wich doesn't change anything...

Answer (score 1):

Delete `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json`, and delete the file `.npmrc` in your C:\Users\your name, run `npm install` again.

Comment: I don't think this will help. This appears to be a Gyp problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I already did this  and it doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to create a project the `C:\WINDOWS\system32` directory. This is a Windows folder and shouldn't be use (and has more security restrictions than a folder owned by your own user).

Switch to a folder that belongs to your user, such as a folder on your Desktop, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the few steps to follow to fix it up:)

1. Delete node_modules folder and delete package-lock.json
2. **npm install**

finally *npm run serve*

Answer (score -3):

Please use `yarn` instead of `npm`.

ex:

1. Delete `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json`.
2. Run `cmd` and input

   `yarn`

   `yarn start`

I hope you solve the problem.
Thank you for your watching my answer.

Comment: This is a Gyp problem. Both Yarn and Node use Gyp to compile extensions. Your solution will not help.

Comment: Thks for your answer ! I already tried with yarn and it don't change anything too.